# jQuery drag and drop prevent

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a simple drawing application, with which you can color cells of a table, and if you hold the mouse button down, you can color multiple cells as you move the mouse. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mFzkG/21/

It works well, the only problem is that in some cases on mousehold the browser thinks I am doing a drag and drop so it doesn't stop on mouseup, only if I click with the mouse.

Does anybody know a way to prevent the drag and drop function or have any idea how to work around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
            $('td').mousedown(function(e) {    
                e.preventDefault();
                isMouseDown = true;
            });
```

You may also want to add your `mouseup` event to the whole body so that if the mouse goes outside of the box and then the button is let go of, it still resets.

```
            $("body").mouseup(function() {
                isMouseDown = false;
            });
```

On a side note, don't put `html` and `body` tags in jsfiddle or `style` tags in the css pane.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! It's awesome! Also thanks for your side notes!